# Radio Button dentro de Funcion con Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Quisiera saber que error tengo ya que al abrir la siguiente ventana quiero que tambien este seleccionado por defecto el radio button de la opcion1 pero solo en la primera ventana esta seleccionado por defecto, en la segunda no.

```
from tkinter import *

def nueva_ventana():
    ven = Toplevel(raíz)

    var2 = IntVar()
    var2.set(1)

    Label(ven, text = "Opciones").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
    Radiobutton(ven, text = "Opcion1", variable=var2, value = 1).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    Radiobutton(ven, text = "Opcion2", variable=var2, value = 2).grid(row=2, sticky=W)

raíz = Tk()
var = IntVar()
var.set(1)

Label(raíz, text = "Opciones").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
Radiobutton(raíz, text = "Opcion1", variable=var, value = 1).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
Radiobutton(raíz, text = "Opcion2", variable=var, value = 2).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
Button(raíz, text = "OK", command=nueva_ventana).grid(row=4, sticky=W)

raíz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el recolector de basura que es implacable. El GC considera inútil todo objeto que esté en memoria pero no tenga al menos una referencia a él activa. En cuanto detecta que no hay al menos una variable referenciando un objeto (contador de referencias a 0), lo "mata" sin piedad inmediatamente, en la RAM no hay espacio para cosas inútiles...

`var2` es una variable local a la función `nueva_ventana`, en cuanto ésta retorna (lo que tarda en generar los widgets) la variable como variable local es eliminada y el objeto `tkinter.IntVar` se queda sin referencias lo que hace que el GC lo mande a mejor vida y libere el espacio de memoria que ocupaba. El resultado es que los pobres RBs se quedan sin su preciada variable, el GC la ha matado.

La solución obvia es llevarse la variable al ámbito global de alguna forma, por ejemplo declarándola como global o definiéndola fuera de la función directamente:

```
import tkinter as tk


def nueva_ventana():
    global var2
    ven = tk.Toplevel(raíz)

    var2 = tk.IntVar(value=1)

    tk.Label(ven, text="Opciones").grid(row=0, sticky=tk.W)
    tk.Radiobutton(
        ven, text="Opcion1", variable=var2, value=1
        ).grid(row=1, sticky=tk.W)

    tk.Radiobutton(
        ven, text="Opcion2", variable=var2, value=2
        ).grid(row=2, sticky=tk.W)


raíz = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar()
var.set(1)

tk.Label(raíz, text="Opciones").grid(row=0, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Radiobutton(
    raíz, text="Opcion1", variable=var, value=1
    ).grid(row=1, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Radiobutton(
    raíz, text="Opcion2", variable=var, value=2
    ).grid(row=2, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Button(raíz, text="OK", command=nueva_ventana).grid(row=4, sticky=tk.W)

raíz.mainloop()
```

Ten en cuenta que el problema se volverá a repetir si abres más de una ventana secundaria al mismo tiempo, solo la última tendrá su `var2` viva, por la misma razón que antes.

Otra opción es generar un nuevo atributo de la instancia de `Toplevel` y asignarle una referencia a la variable, dado que tkinter mantiene viva una referencia a la instancia de la ventana mientras no se cierre, la variable tendrá también una referencia mientras exista su ventana y el GC le perdonará la vida:

```
import tkinter as tk


def nueva_ventana():
    ven = tk.Toplevel(raíz)
    var2 = tk.IntVar(value=1)
    ven.var2 = var2   # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    tk.Label(ven, text="Opciones").grid(row=0, sticky=tk.W)
    tk.Radiobutton(
        ven, text="Opcion1", variable=var2, value=1
        ).grid(row=1, sticky=tk.W)

    tk.Radiobutton(
        ven, text="Opcion2", variable=var2, value=2
        ).grid(row=2, sticky=tk.W)


raíz = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar()
var.set(1)

tk.Label(raíz, text="Opciones").grid(row=0, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Radiobutton(
    raíz, text="Opcion1", variable=var, value=1
    ).grid(row=1, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Radiobutton(
    raíz, text="Opcion2", variable=var, value=2
    ).grid(row=2, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Button(raíz, text="OK", command=nueva_ventana).grid(row=4, sticky=tk.W)

raíz.mainloop()
```

pero yo no me complicaría, la POO existe para algo, una clase que derive de `TopLevel` y punto:

```
import tkinter as tk


class NuevaVentana(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.radbtns_var = tk.IntVar(self, value=1)

        tk.Label(self, text="Opciones").grid(row=0, sticky=tk.W)
        tk.Radiobutton(
            self, text="Opcion1", variable=self.radbtns_var, value=1
            ).grid(row=1, sticky=tk.W)

        tk.Radiobutton(
            self, text="Opcion2", variable=self.radbtns_var, value=2
            ).grid(row=2, sticky=tk.W)


raíz = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar()
var.set(1)

tk.Label(raíz, text="Opciones").grid(row=0, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Radiobutton(
    raíz, text="Opcion1", variable=var, value=1
    ).grid(row=1, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Radiobutton(
    raíz, text="Opcion2", variable=var, value=2
    ).grid(row=2, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Button(
    raíz, text="OK", command=lambda: NuevaVentana(raíz)
    ).grid(row=4, sticky=tk.W)

raíz.mainloop()
```

Ahora puedes abrir las ventanas que quieras, como atributo de instancia la variable existirá hasta que la propia instancia de `Toplevel` se destruya.