# Tkinter radiobutton no funciona bien dentro de un toplevel

Tags: python, tkinter

Bueno amigos Tengo un gran problema, quiero crear dos radiobuttons en un Toplevel, uno de los radiobuttons esta seleccionado por defecto. En la ventana raíz funciona a la perfección, pero en el toplevel no funciona seleccionar automáticamente uno y estoy usando el mismo código. Quizás el problema es con toplevel o se me esta escapando algo de la mano. Aquí les dejo un pequeño ejemplo. Gracias de antemano. Los radiobuttons del root y el toplevel deben ser diferentes, son de variables diferentes.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def nueva_ventana(padre):
    windows = tk.Toplevel(padre)
    windows.geometry('300x220')
    VARIABLE = tk.IntVar()
    VARIABLE.set(1)
    ttk.Radiobutton(windows, text="1",variable=VARIABLE, value=1).pack()
    ttk.Radiobutton(windows, text="2",variable=VARIABLE, value=2).pack()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x220')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('Radio Button no funciona')
ttk.Button(root, text="TopLevel", command=lambda :nueva_ventana(root)).pack()
VARIABLE_ROOT = tk.IntVar()
VARIABLE_ROOT.set(1)
ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="1",variable=VARIABLE_ROOT, value=1).pack()
ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="2",variable=VARIABLE_ROOT, value=2).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la solucion, el problema es el recolector de basura de python, lo explican mejor en esta otra publicacion.

[Radio Button dentro de Funcion con Tkinter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/361812/radio-button-dentro-de-funcion-con-tkinter?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Ya que en la función `nueva_ventana` trabajas con la "padre", no necesitas la variable `VARIABLE` ya que tienes que trabajar con `VARIABLE_ROOT`.

Te adjunto aquí como debería estar tu código

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def nueva_ventana(root):
    windows = tk.Toplevel(root)
    windows.geometry('300x220')
    ttk.Radiobutton(windows, text="1",variable=VARIABLE_ROOT, value=1).pack()
    ttk.Radiobutton(windows, text="2",variable=VARIABLE_ROOT, value=2).pack()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x220')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('Radio Button no funciona')
ttk.Button(root, text="TopLevel", command=lambda :nueva_ventana(root)).pack()
VARIABLE_ROOT = tk.IntVar()
VARIABLE_ROOT.set(1)
ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="1",variable=VARIABLE_ROOT, value=1).pack()
ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="2",variable=VARIABLE_ROOT, value=2).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Si tienes alguna duda escribe un comentario. Un saludo!

Comment: El radiobutton del padre lo hice para que vieran que funciona la auntoseleccion en el root y no en el toplevel,